# Prove the following statement: $\forall r\in \mathbb{R^+}$,if r is irrational then $\sqrt r$ is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove the following  statement: $\forall r\in \mathbb{R^+}$,if r is irrational then $\sqrt r$ is irrational

**My attempt:**

if suppose $\sqrt r $ is rational

then there exists $p,q \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that

$\frac{p}{q}=\sqrt r $ where p and q are prime to each other

$\rightarrow p=q \sqrt r \rightarrow p^2=r q^2$

i can't processed further can any help

Comment: $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: As @N74 says, $p,q \in \Bbb N$!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$r={p^2\over q^2}$ so it is rational contradiction.

Comment: ..how it is irrational can you exaplain

Answer (score 1):

easier to do contrapositive, if $\sqrt{r}$ is rational then so is $r$.

If 
 $\sqrt{r} = p/q$ with $p$ and $q$ integers then
$$
r = p^2/q^2
$$
so it is a ratio of integers so it is rational.

Taking the contrapositive, we have the statement you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Then $r = p^2/q^2$, which is rational, a contradiction.

Comment: @user49640...can u expalin bit more

Comment: $p^2/q^2$ is a quotient of integers.